# How do I filter basing on the vocabulary value?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using the REST api to retrieve articles and some data related to  them. I managed to get the articles belonging to Red (which is a term of the taxonomy "color") using a view and contextual filters. Now I want to list all the terms of the taxonomy color without the articles .. The result must be Red, green, cyan , blue ... How can I do that?

Comment: Create "Taxonomy" view with a filter or "Vocabulary: Color". Or if you want your view to show terms from any vocabulary, then add a Contextual Filter on "Vocabulary" similar to your Node view

Comment: thank you very much